# Ubuntu One and 'Something has gone wrong'

Tags: ubuntu-one

When I try to login via browser (Chrome, Firefox) to Ubuntu One, I get following error:

> Something has gone wrong Sorry about
>   that. This problem has been reported
>   to Ubuntu One engineers and we'll fix
>   it as quickly as possible. This may be
>   a temporary problem, so try again in a
>   few minutes. You can also review the
>   current status of Ubuntu One which may
>   contain more information about this
>   issue.

I can, however, go to machine adding page on Ubuntu One. I'm using only one computer, and it is listed there several times. I tried to delete every entries there and adding my computer once more, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

What blocks connecting my computer to Ubuntu One cloud?
It happened ever since I remember. I really wanna use it to store my 100GB stuff, but I just can't connect :)

Comment: Consider reporting a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was fixed by contacting support, my account was broken and they've fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if your computer is connected to Ubuntu One? You can see this on the terminal by running:

```
u1sdtool --status
```

That should show online and connected as true. If you're connected and you're still getting an error when trying to log into the Ubuntu One site or your computer is not connected, then your best bet is to submit a support request at https://one.ubuntu.com/support/contact You don't need to be logged in to send the request.

Comment: pk@pk-laptop:~$ u1sdtool --status
State: READY
    connection: Not User With Network
    description: ready to connect
    is_connected: False
    is_error: False
    is_online: False
    queues: WORKING_ON_BOTH
So I'll better try to send request...

Comment: try to do: `u1sdtool --connect` the again --status and see if the output is different.

Answer (score 0):

Check your terminal after executing command:

```
ubuntuone-launch
```

Maybe you got any Python's backtrace or something. Worth try ;)

Comment: terminal shows nothing after that command :( PS. kkrzysiu from telepathy-sunshine? where is PPA for telepathy-onetczat? ;P